# Jasmine async test passes in SpecRunner but fails from command line (grunt-contrib-jasmine)

Tags: javascript, ajax, tdd, jasmine

I have a test for a method that will pass if I run it via the SpecRunner but will fail if I run the test from the command line (e.g. grunt jasmine).

The test is shown below.  The doSomething() method makes an AJAX call and uses the response to create a UL element within the DIV with id="my-test".

```
describe( 'my AJAX method', function() {
 beforeEach( function() {
   this.$myTest = $('<div id="my-test"></div>');
   this.$myTest.appendTo($('body'));
 });
 afterEach( function() {
   this.$myTest.remove();
 });
 it('should create a UL from the result of the Ajax request', function() {
   runs(function() {
     myObj.doSomething();  // this makes an AJAX request and builds a UL from the response
   });
   waitsFor(function() {
     return( this.$myTest.find('ul').length > 0 );
   }, 'UL has been created', 2000);
   runs( function() {
     expect(this.$myTest.find('ul').length).toEqual(1);
   });
 });
});
```

The error message from the command line is:-

```
Running "jasmine:src" (jasmine) task
Testing jasmine specs via phantom
............x
my AJAX method:: should create a UL from the result of the Ajax request: failed
 timeout: timed out after 2000 msec waiting for UL has been created (1)
13 specs in 1.749s.
>> 1 failures
Warning: Task "jasmine:src" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Add more details about the issue you're getting (error messages, stacktraces, etc. See rules (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the body element isn't created right away when using grunt-contrib-jasmine so your #my-test div is probably not appended to the body element. You can try

```
$('body').ready(function {
    // Do stuff with body.
});
```

if you're using jQuery.

Old question, but maybe it can help someone searching.